# How to troubleshoot a history.go(-1) failure on one machine and only in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, html5-history

history.go(-1) has no effect in iFrame from different domain, but works in chrome on another machine.

Given a start page with an iFrame from a different domain.
And a FirstIFramedPage.html with a link to SecondIFramedPage in the different domain.
When I click on a back button with onClick="window.history.go(-1)" it has no effect.
**However**, it does have the desired affect (to navigate the frame back to FirstIFramedPage.html) in every other browser I've tested AND on another machine with the same version of Chrome.
chrome: Version 66.0.3359.181 (Official Build) (64-bit)

I have a fully working example here: https://github.com/jimlesch/ChromeIFrameHistoryFail
the readme.txt has instructions on how to reproduce this issue.

What I've tried:

1. running in incognito mode.
2. disabling extensions.
3. using an iframe from the same domain (works as expected, but not possible in my scenario)
4. Uninstalling and reinstalling Chrome.
5. Installing Chrome Beta to see if it behaved differently (still fails for me on 5)
6. Looking at chrome://tracing (could not make heads or tails of it)

I am looking for help on how to further isolate this issue, since I cannot reproduce it on another windows 10 machine with the same version of chrome. Thanks for any help you could provide.

Comment: update: I am also reporting here: http://dev.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines

Comment: update: open bug report here https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=814355&can=2&start=0&num=100&q=history.go&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=

Comment: It would appear this is a chrome bug introduced in field trials of "Site isolation". These field trials get applied to 10% of the stable build (and 90% in beta builds).  I was able to revert to expected behavior by choosing to "opt out" in "Site isolation trial opt-out".  Also see this duplicate bug for a richer discussion: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=845923

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear this is a chrome bug introduced in field trials of "Site isolation". These field trials get applied to 10% of the stable build (and 90% in beta builds). 
I was able to revert to expected behavior by choosing to "opt out" in "Site isolation trial opt-out". This setting is available under: chrome://flags/#enable-site-per-process.

Also see this duplicate bug for a richer discussion: bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=845923